# Retrieve a property from json object in logic app

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

In my logic app I have following json object sitting in a string variable, after this step I am using parson json step. But not sure if this is correct step.

```
{
    "id": "1qFIkKt61MPZFybZhTK",
    "object": "object1",
    "created": 109,

    "options": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "message": {
                "role": "admin",
                "content": "{\n  \"TicketId\": \"5477\"\n}"
            },
            "reason": "stop"
        }
    ],
    "department": {
        "id": 244,
        "code": 182
     }
}
```

I tried following

[image]

I want to retrieve ticketId in the above json object in logic app. Using online jsonviewer the json object looks good.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it a few ways.  If it were me, I'd do it like this ...

[image: JSON]

... using this following expression in the second step ...

```
json(first(variables('JSON')?['options'])?['message']?['content'])?['TicketId']
```

... that will give you the `TicketId` property from the parsed JSON.

Some other examples for you ...

**Department** = `variables('JSON')?['department']?['id']`

**Reason** = `first(variables('JSON')?['options'])?['reason']`

Comment: thank you so much. just trying to understand the expression json(first(variables('JSON')?['options'])?['message']?['content'])?['TicketId'],  what is "first" here? and what if I want to retrieve any other element in json object ?

Comment: `first()` is being used because the data you're trying to get to is contained within an array, you can also use the notation `[0]` to retrieve the first item in the array.  If you want to retrieve others then give me an example and I'll tell you.  :-)  This may help as well ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference

Comment: thank you for the explanation,  if I want to retrieve  reason and department(id), what are the expression(s) we should use here?

Comment: Answer updated.  Untested but should work.