# how to retrieve value from http response in logic app

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

[image]

i'm trying to get value of "job_number" value 987 and also "group_role" value 89 from http response body in logic app which looks like this

```
{
  "body": {
    "id": "7666",
    "object": "object",
    "created": 123,
    "options": [
      {
        "job": 2,
        "job_details": {
          "role": "admin",
          "content": "{\n \"job_number\": \"987\"\n}"
        },
        "job_action": "inprogress"
      }
    ],
    "dept": {
      "grpup_id": 2,
      "group_role": 89,
      "total_count": 23
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking to use parseJson and compose actions to retrieve job_number and group_role.But I'm not sure how to create schema in the parseJson step for "options" property as it is collection of objects within body.
How to create sample payload for the above body object and then retrieve these values in compose step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve a property from json object in logic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76986418/retrieve-a-property-from-json-object-in-logic-app)

Comment: You asked this question the other day and I answered it for you.  You even marked it as correct.  Are you still having trouble?  It's the same concept.

Comment: yes, I'm having trouble accessing http response object, getting template errors The response object has 3 parts and just need body part and in body part just need to retrieve job_number value. Just uploaded response object.

Comment: when I view response object from https://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ I can see that "\n" are disappearing at job_number property, but I think in logic app it is not happening.

Comment: You're thinking too hard about it.  The \n's are just line breaks, they mean nothing.  My answer from the other day will work, you just need to change it to suit the property names.

Comment: @Skin, thank you. I was earlier using hardcode body part for understanding purpose, but in reality it is entire response object and within that I would like to  pick body part and retrieve a variable  in it .How can I just select body part? What operation / action should I select here?

Comment: You should see the response body in your dynamic content.  The problem is though, if you want to apply additional expressions to it, you need to type it out completely, OR, go to the `expressions` tab in your operation where you want to put the expression from my previous answer, type anything at all, like `s` or something, then flick back to the dynamic content, select the body response, then go back to `expressions` and remove the leading `s`, now you have the correct starting point.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

As you said if you have extra **`\n`** or **`\`** in http response you can use below design:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**For group role:**

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['dept']?['group_role']
```

**For options in for each:**

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['options']
```

**For job number:**

```
json(replace(replace(items('for_each')?['job_details']['content'],'\n',''),'\',''))?['job_number']
```

In expression section you need to use the above formulas:

[image]

**`Parse_Json Schema:`**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "properties": {
                "created": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "dept": {
                    "properties": {
                        "group_role": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "grpup_id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "total_count": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "object": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "options": {
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "job": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "job_action": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "job_details": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "content": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "role": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "job",
                            "job_details",
                            "job_action"
                        ],
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['dept']?['group_role']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose_2": {
                        "inputs": "@json(replace(replace(items('for_each')?['job_details']['content'],'\\n',''),'\\',''))?['job_number']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['options']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "body": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "created": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "dept": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "group_role": {
                                                "type": "integer"
                                            },
                                            "grpup_id": {
                                                "type": "integer"
                                            },
                                            "total_count": {
                                                "type": "integer"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "object": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "options": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "job": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "job_action": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "job_details": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "content": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "role": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "object"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "job",
                                                "job_details",
                                                "job_action"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: @RithwikBoja thank you. Can you share the expression you have used in the Parse Json step to fetch body section of response object

Comment: It is https://i.imgur.com/hnmQ1N9.png triggerBody()